# Why is my function returning the correct value, even when I am giving 8 as the first number?

Tags: c++, recursion

[image]

I have made a function for calculating HCF of a number using recursion. The problem I am facing is that, in expression (p%q), as p = 8, and q = 12. My compiler is just making p = 12 in the recursion cycle, even though the expression (8%12) = 8.

So the recursive cycle "**hcf(q, p%q)**" should be of form (8,8), in the second call to function, but it appears to be (12,8). I am completely unable to understand how is this happening. With my logic hcf returned by function should have been 8, if I give **8 as p (first number)**.

***Note: My IDE is visual studio***.

```
int hcf(int p , int q )
{
    cout << endl << p << endl << q << endl; // To check what's happening with remainder function in each recursive cycle.
    if (p%q != 0)
    {
        hcf(q, p%q);
    }
    else
        return q;
}

int main()
{
    int f, s;
    cout << "Enter first number\n";
    cin >> f;
    cout << "Enter second number\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "The HCF of the numbers is: \t" << hcf(f , s) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**: Your understanding is not correct, program is generating right output.

```
hcf(p = 8, q = 12)
  hcf(12(q), 8 % 12(p % q)) = hcf(p = 12, q = 8)
    hcf(8(q), 12 % 8(p % q)) = hcf(p = 8, q = 4)
      return 4 (q)
```

> in expression (p%q), as p = 8, and q = 12. My compiler is just making p = 12

Because you are explicitly passing second argument `q` as first argument in recrusive call.

**Issue 2**: You should replace `hcf(q, p%q);` with `return hcf(q, p%q);`

Comment: hcf(q, p%q); should be hcf(p, p%q);That's the right way to calculate HCF.

Comment: Ok, I just understood my mistake.

Comment: @LiuYubo Actually arguments should be `large % small` and `small`. Order doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, why it should be return hcf(q, p%q) instead of hcf(q, p%q)?

Comment: @MMH Because `int hcf(int p , int q )` returns an `int`. But the `if` path is just calculating the result but not returning anything. So the outcome is undefined.

Comment: @MMH Undefined behaviors are not required to throw an error. If you enable all warnings you may get a warning on many compilers and static analysers. `int a[3]; a[100] = 12;` is UB but may not give an error.